# Where is Zambesi located in DC Comics?

Tags: dc, comics

What part of Africa is Zambesi, Vixen’s hometown located in DC Comics?

Is it East, West, South or Central Africa?

Answer (score 1):

Though Zambesi is actually a river in Eastern Africa, the exact location of Zambesi (in the DC comics) is unclear. It is usually described as Central African in the comics, but also in the shadow of Mount Kilimanjaro in Tanzania as well as on the 'slave coast' of West Africa. Mustapha Maksai's last name is Swahili (East African).

So basically it's 'unclear' since the comics have been inconsistent in mentioning the exact position of Zambesi.

[Source](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Zambesi)

Comment: "*It is usually described as Central African,[2] but also in the shadow of Mount Kilimanjaro in Tanzania[3] as well as on the slave coast of West Africa[4].*" - You'd do well to track down those numbered sources and add them to your answer rather than just basically regurgitating the wiki article. Wikis are notorious for being crap.

Comment: You might also want to note that the comics do address it directly, they're just inconsistent about it.